# Button transition on Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I make speech recognition application. But i have a problem. How can i make an transition from letter category menu to speech recognition menu, but don' add new class or new layout. Example. When i click A button, it will get A menu with speech recognition menu and so on. Sorry, i'm new in Android studio.

Here is the code for Speech Recognition

```
public class MainGame extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView jawabanTxt;
    private String textA;
    TextView textView;

    SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
    Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_game_act);
        jawabanTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jawabanTxt);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);



    }

    public void getSpeechInput(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,Locale.getDefault());


    if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Perangkat anda tidak  mendukung", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,data);

        switch (requestCode){
            case 10:
            if ((resultCode == RESULT_OK &&data != null)) {
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                jawabanTxt.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
            }
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the category

```
public class HurufActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final TextView ATxt;
        ImageButton aBtn;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.huruf_activity);

        ATxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aTxt);
        aBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.aBtn);

        aBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    TextView textA = (TextView) ATxt.getText();
                    if (textA == ATxt) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(HurufActivity.this, MainGame.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

From this:

[image]

To This:

[image]

Thank You

Comment: You could potentially do something like this: https://caster.io/lessons/transcribe-an-audio-voice-file-to-text-with-google-cloud-speech-api

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong is here:

```
try {
                TextView textA = (TextView) ATxt.getText();
                if (textA == ATxt) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(HurufActivity.this, MainGame.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

I think, that this try - catch block is unnecessary and this `(TextView) ATxt.getText();` will not work.

Just do something like this:

```
aBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(HurufActivity.this, MainGame.class);
              startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, because you need to set another listener to "B" button.